Use Microsoft Graph authentication to download SharePoint document by direct link (WebUrl)
I am trying to update a SharePoint CSOM application to use the Microsoft Graph API.
The existing program used credentials (username + password) from the SharePoint CSOM to download documents from SharePoint using the System.Net.WebClient library. What I can't work out how to pass the authentication details from Microsoft graph to SharePoint.
Existing CSOM code:
ClientContext SharePoint;
remotePath = "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{site}/{list}/{filename}";
localPath = "C:\\temp\\{filename}";

//Authentication in CSOM using username/password not shown

using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = SharePoint.Credentials;
    client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
    client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(remotePath, localPath).Wait();
}

With the Microsoft Graph I ahve attempted the below:
var parentWindowHandle = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(App.Current.MainWindow).Handle;
var credentialOptions = new Azure.Identity.Broker.InteractiveBrowserCredentialBrokerOptions(parentWindowHandle)
{
    ClientId = clientId,
    TenantId = tenantId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

credential = new Azure.Identity.InteractiveBrowserCredential(credentialOptions);    
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential);
remotePath = "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{site}/{list}/{filename}";
localPath = "C:\\temp\\{filename}";

var tokenRequestContext = new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);

using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.Token);
    client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
    client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(remotePath, localPath).Wait();
}

The response I get is:
401 UNAUTHORIZED
I have also tried getting a token for the scope "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/.default", the result is the same.
I have tried with and without "User-Agent: Other" and "X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f" headers.
I see the same generic 401 if I paste the token returned by GetTokenAsync() into Postman.
Current API permissions (There are a lot of similar permissions from testing):


Could you include API permissions image of your app registration by editing your question? Please confirm what authentication flow you want to use like interactive flow or username password flow?

Hi @GeneralUn-Co Any update?

@Sridevi Sorry Stack overflow doesn't seem to send me notifications. I will have a look now

Please check and let me know if it works : )

@Sridevi I have added the current API permissions screenshot. From your answer below it looks like I need to request Files.Read.All

YEs, you need either Files.Read or Files.Read.All Microsoft Graph permission of Delegated type.

Initially, I registered one application and granted Files.Read.All Microsoft Graph permission of Delegated type as below:

If you are using interactive flow for authentication, you need to add http://localhost as redirect URI under "Mobile & Desktop applications" platform and enable public client flow option:

I have one file named Document.docx in sridoclib drive of DemoSite like this:

To download this file locally using Microsoft Graph, you can make use of below sample c# code that asks user to login first and downloads file:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientId = "appId";

        var driveId = "driveId";
        var driveItemId = "fileId";
        var localFilePath = "C:\\test\\Document.docx";

        var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
        {
            TenantId = tenantId,
            ClientId = clientId
        };

        var credential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential);

        try
        {
            using (var stream = await graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[driveItemId].Content.GetAsync())
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("File downloaded successfully to: " + localFilePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in local path where file downloaded successfully as below:

You can run below API calls in Graph Explorer to get the values of site ID, drive ID and driveItem ID respectively:
Site ID:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/sites/siteName


Drive ID:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteIDfromAbove/drives?$filter=name eq 'driveName'


DriveItem / File ID:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/driveIDfromAbove/root/children?$filter=name eq 'DocumentName.docx'&$select=id,name


Reference:
Download driveItem content - Microsoft Graph v1.0

The filter for the name in the Drive ID query does not work, as long as the query is valid syntax it returns all drives within the site (Checked in both postman and C#). I was able to manually search the results to find the id though.
With this I am able to download documents but it is far more complicated than the old method. Is there no way to use the direct URL as per the question title?

AFAIK, that's the only way to download file using Graph SDK in c#. Using direct URL there is no way. Alternatively, you can click download URL link that you get from this API call response GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/driveIDfromAbove/root/children?$filter=name eq 'DocumentName.docx' https://i.imgur.com/JqnvRYt.png

@GeneralUn-Co Any update?
